# How to change when packages are excecuted

Tags: go

I have a package A in Go that looks like

```
package A

var Something int

func Do_something() {

    Something = 100

}
```

where do_something in package A is called in main.go

```
package main

import "example.com/this_project/A"

func main() {

    A.Do_something()

}
```

That works well, but now I add package B.

```
package B

import (
    "example.com/this_project/A"
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

_ = do_something_else()

func do_something_else() {

    fmt.Println("%s is the value of something", strconv.Itoa(A.Something))        

}

func Some_other_function() {

    do_whatever()

}
```

Some_other_function will also get called in main.go

```
package main

import "example.com/this_project/A"
import "example.com/this_project/B"

func main() {

    A.Do_something()
    B.Some_other_function()

}
```

When I run this program, I expect it to output

```
100
```

But instead, it outputs

```
0
```

I think this means that package B is running before main.go, so I tried using time.sleep, but it just caused the entire project to stop. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: You should generally avoid using globals within a package. Besides, it appears to be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: Package other than `main` are not directly executed. You can see the defined [initialization order in the language spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Program_initialization_and_execution)

Comment: `do_whatever` is not defined in your code, so it's impossible to say what it "should" do, other than perhaps not compile.

Answer (score 3):

All global variables are initialized before `main` starts running. Because of that, this line:

```
_ = do_something_else()
```

will run before `main` starts, which will print the current value of the variable, which is 0 at that point.